# How to check Alert Dialog is open only one times instead of multiple new dialog box after onTap in flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog

I am working on my flutter application and I want to check whether the alert dialog is open or not on the screen . Can anyone tell me how to do that, now everytime i press ontap and it will appear a new dialog box. how can i only appear one dialog box instead of multiple of new dialog box ?

I have try bool, ontap cancel all not working.

```
Future? _dialog;

Future<void> _checkTimer() async {

  if (_dialog == null) {
    _dialog =  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

    showTimer(context);
    await _dialog;
    _dialog = null;
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }


}
```

```
showTimer(BuildContext context) {
  // set up the buttons
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use

  if (didUserTouchedScreen = true){
    Container alert = Container(child: _imageslideshowProductDetailstimer());
    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {

              didUserTouchedScreen = false;
              // _checkTimer();
              return true;
            },
            child: alert);
      },
    ).then((_) => didUserTouchedScreen = false);
  }}
```

```
behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
onTapDown: (tapdown) {
  print("down");

_checkTimer();

},
onTapCancel: (){print('up');_checkTimer();}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code that contains `onTapDown` and `onTapCancel` you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a boolean state, let's call it `isButtonActive`. The button is enabled/disabled depending on the value of this state. When the button is pressed, set the state to false, and when the dialog box is closed, set the state to true.

Below is an example code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isButtonActive = true;

  showTimer(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() {
      isButtonActive = false;
    });

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: const [
            Text('qwerty'),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        isButtonActive = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('총톤수'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: isButtonActive ? () => showTimer(context) : null,
          child: const Text('총톤수'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi i try ur solution but when i tap on other widget the dialogbox doest not come out anymore.